# Azure Function not stateless

Tags: c#, reflection, azure-functions

I have a .NetCore 2 Azure Function (runtime 2) on a **consumption plan** that makes use of reflection, it loads an assembly in the current Domain (`Assembly.LoadFrom()`) and does other stuff with it.

Most times the function runs fine, but sometimes it complains that the assembly is already loaded. I though this should not be possible as functions in the consumption plan should be running statelessly...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to abstractions: nothing is perfect, everything leaks slightly...

Comment: It's stateless yes, but your app domain will remain loaded indefinitely unless you unload it.

Comment: Race condition?

Comment: Thanks @davidg, as far as I know loaded assemblies can’t be unloaded, so I’d have to use a new app domain each time...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stateless yes, but your app domain will remain loaded indefinitely unless you unload it. As you are using Azure Functions v2, this means you are in the land of .NET Core, meaning you don't have an `AppDomain` you can use. However, you can use [`AssemblyLoadContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=netcore-2.2). For example:

```
public class FooContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    public FooContext() : base(isCollectible: true)
    {
    }
}
```

And now:

```
var myLoader = new FooContext();

var assembly = myLoader.LoadFromAssemblyPath("your-path");

// Now do stuff with "assembly" as you did before
```

Finally, remember to clean up:

```
myLoader.Unload();
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! To clarify, it seems that unloadability is only available from .NetCore 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability

Answer (score 0):

Azure function is stateless and as David said in comments:

> your app domain will remain loaded indefinitely unless you unload it

If you still want to load it, you can try to use the code below:

```
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(dllPath);
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(fileData);
```

But this code can't load the associated assembly.